# Call __get() on protected properties with -> operator?

Tags: php, magic-methods, lazy-loading

My team is using lazyloading techniques to load sub-objects from our database.  To do this we're using the magic __get() method and making a database call.  All of our properties are protected so the __get method gets called from outside of the object but our issue is that it doesn't get called from within the object without using `$this->__get($name);`

So my question is:  Is it possible to force __get() to be called with the normal chaining operator even from within the object?

If I want to chain object access I currently have to do:

```
$this->__get('subObject')->__get('subObject')->__get('subObject')
```

Is it possible to write the following, but have it still call __get()?

```
$this->subObject->subObject->subObject
```

Thanks,
Jordan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jordan,

PHP won't call the `__get()` method unless the property is inaccessible—either because it doesn't exist, or because of visibility. When the property is hidden from the calling scope the __get() method is called because the property is inaccessible. When the property is referenced and is available to the calling scope, __get() will *never* fire. (It's not meant to fire for an existing/accessible property.)

To work around this you have to rename your internal properties. Either prefix them with a name, underscore, or store them in a common array parameter with a special name. The following is somewhat contrived, but it ought to demonstrate how you can deal with this situation.

```
class MyObject {
   protected $lazyloads = array();

   protected function lazyload($relation) {
     // ...
   }

   public function __get($key) {
     if (isset($this->lazyloads[$key]) {
       return $this->lazyloads[$key];
     } else {
       return $this->lazyload($key);
     }
   }
}
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Answer (score 0):

@Robert K Or (for example):

```
class A
{
    protected $objects = array();

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if(isset($this->objects[$name])) {
            return $this->objects[$name];
        }
        return null; // or throw \Exception
    }
}
class B
{
    protected $objects = array();

    public function __get($name)
    {
        // for example: $this->objects[$name] is type of A
        if(isset($this->objects[$name])) {
            return $this->objects[$name];
        }
        return null; // or throw \Exception
    }
}
```

each returned object must have a magic method `__get` that returns an object.